# How to customize my Gesture Responder Chain with views: "Swipeable" UITabBarController -> UIViewController -> PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I am having an issue with trying to customize my gesture responder chain

I come from Cocoa/macOS & Mouse Events, and the concept of gestures has been tripping me up

Assumptions based on my research:

- Instead of mouse events being passed to `NSResponders`, There are Tap, Press, and Gesture events.  Tap and Press get passed to `UIResponders`, Gestures are passed to `GestureRecognizers` (owned by a `UIView`)
- The difference between touchBegan/touchMoved/touchEnded and a Gesture recognizer depends on the speed of the finger? ([uigesturerecognizers-vs-touchesbegan-touchesmoved-touchesended-accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851464/uigesturerecognizers-vs-touchesbegan-touchesmoved-touchesended-accuracy)).  So if you tap, and slowly move, the underlying UIView receives the `touchMoved` events.  If you Tap and drag quickly, a gesture is created and passed to the the GestureRecognizer of the underlying `UIView`.  [I am pretty uncertain on this one, so I am opening another SO question to address this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55884239/when-do-finger-events-get-sent-as-gestures-to-uigesturerecognizer-vs-touchesbe)
- When I say "swipe left", I mean the opposite direction your finger goes, and I mean left as in the direction of the navigation animation.  same with "swipe right".

**I have a problem with my "Gestures" not being sent to the Gesture Recognizers I would like. (I originally thought that gestures went to the controllers, but I have since learned that isn't the case, and GestureRecognizers are owned by the Views)**

View Hierarchy:

- "Swipeable" UITabBarController ([SwipeableTabBarController](https://github.com/marcosgriselli/SwipeableTabBarController))

  - UIViewController
  - UIViewController
  - UIViewController (UIView)

    - PageViewController (_PageContentView and _UIQueueingScrollView)

      - CollectionViewController (CollectionView)

So here's what I am trying to make happen:

- If you swipe anywhere on the screen, you will move between the 3 `UIViewControllers` (Thanks `SwipeableTabBarController`)
- If you swipe right on the third right-most `UIViewController`, you will actually flip through the pages of the `PageViewController`)
- If you swipe left on the third `UIViewController` (which holds the `PageViewController`), and you are in the left-most page of the `PageViewController`, you will go left into the second (middle) `UIViewController`

**However**,

- Once you navigate to the right-most `UIViewController`, all swipe gestures are consumed by the `UIQueueingScrollView` on the `UIPageViewController`.  This means that Once you are in the right-most view, you cannot swipe back left to the middle view.  Swiping just flips between pages, (and in the case of being on the left page, nothing happens)
- I have manually enumerated over subviews to find this `UIQueueingScrollView`, and removed all `GestureRecognizers` from it, and this allows the gestures to get passed up to the `SwipeableTabBarController`, so that you can swipe back to the middle view... But this of course breaks the `UIPageViewController`'s scrolling

**My Goal:**

Somehow mutate the GestureRecognizers in the `UIPageViewController` (it looks like I have to do it on it's `_UIQueueingScrollView`), so that

- if you are looking at the left-most page:

  - do a swipe left gesture:

    - will be passed to the GestureRecognizers in `SwipeableTabBarController`. Main UIViewControllers will swap
  - do a swipe right gesture:

    - will be passed to the `GestureRecognizers` in `UIQueueingScrollView`, and the pageview will flip to the next page
- else if you are looking at any other page:

  - all swipe gestures passed to the `UIQueueingScrollView`

My biggest hangup is that I can't just override gesture receivers, I have to create new custom GestureRecognizers and manually attach them to my views... but then I don't know how to have these new custom GestureRecognizers pass the gestures up the view hierarchy