# When do "finger" events get sent as Gestures to UIGestureRecognizer vs touchesBegan/touchesMoved/touchesEnded to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uievent

I come from macOS/Cocoa & Mouse Events, and I'm trying to get a hang of these "Finger"(my own name for it) events

---

My question is:

When a "Finger" event is happening on a `UIView` (let's call `MyView`), when does it get sent as a `Gesture` to a `UIGestureRecognizer` on `MyView`, and when does it get sent as a `touchesBegan/touchesMoved/touchesEnded` to `MyView`

---

I have searched with all possible queries I could think of, and really only found a few decent sources, but nothing that answers exactly what I'm looking for

[touchesBegan, touchesEnded, touchesMoved for moving UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856906/touchesbegan-touchesended-touchesmoved-for-moving-uiview)

[UIGestureRecognizers vs touchesBegan/touchesMoved/touchesEnded (accuracy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851464/uigesturerecognizers-vs-touchesbegan-touchesmoved-touchesended-accuracy)

My best guess right now is that the difference between **touchBegan/touchMoved/touchEnded** and a Gesture recognizer depends on the speed of the finger?

So if you tap, and slowly move, the underlying `UIView` receives the `touchMoved` events.  If you Tap and drag quickly, a gesture is created and passed to the the GestureRecognizer of the underlying `UIView`

My current guess is that when the finger touches down, event runloop detects this finger, and fires a `touchesBegan`.  As you move your finger around, it fires `touchesMoved`.
However, if you are moving quickly enough, or in a way that the runtime thinks that you're making a gesture, it instead creates a Gesture and fires a message to the `UIGestureRecognizer`, instead of sending `touchesMoved`

I am currently trying to test out this hypothesis, but it's pretty tedious and I don't have a really good sample project to test with, so I figured I'd crowdsource some insight if possible.  I'll report back if I figure it out myself as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complicated (or can be), but the *basic* rule is simple. [For additional details, see [my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_touch_delivery).]

A finger is a UITouch which is wrapped in a UIEvent for delivery. Delivery proceeds touches began, touches moved, touches moved ... touches ended / cancelled at which point that finger is no longer there.

As a touch (finger) appears, the initial UITouch / UIEvent (touches began) is sent to *both* the view *and* its gesture recognizer(s) *and* any gesture recognizers higher up the view hierarchy. That way, touches are delivered to the view as normal, and at the same the gesture recognizers can be thinking about the gesture.

That keeps happening repeatedly (touches moved) until either the touch is lifted (touches ended) or one of the gesture recognizers recognizes. In the latter case, all the other g.r.s are forced to fail, the touch is cancelled to the view, and only the recognizing g.r. gets the rest of the touches as they proceed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You have come by my questions for years and I always appreciate it.  Some follow-up, what is a g.r.s, and g.r.?  I also read that passage in your book, and now I'm wondering what happens if: the front-most view does not respond to `touches...`, so it passes the event up the responder chain-- However, that event eventually creates a Gesture as well.  Would the gesture be sent to that front-most view still? or would it move up the chain as well, the same way the touch event did?

Comment: `g.r` gesture recognizer

Comment: Well if you look at my book you see the answer: first we determine the "hit-test view".